# Windows file and path names for local drive with CreateFile() WinAPI

Tags: file, winapi, path

An application that has been running just fine with Windows XP and Windows 7 suddenly developed problems with Windows 10 Pro. However, with Windows 10 IoT Enterprise, it seems to work fine. It also seemed to work fine back in May of 2018 with Windows 10, yet with newer installs of Windows 10, it doesn't work.

After some investigation, we found that the application seems to be unable to create the set of files that it uses for persistent data with Windows 10 Pro.

Looking further, we found that the complete pathname was incorrect. It appears that the pathname to the directory where files were being stored, though not properly constructed, worked fine with Windows XP and Windows 7, but not with Windows 10 Pro.

The pathname being generated looked like this (those are path backslashes and not C/C++ backslashes for escaping a character):

```
\C:\DirA\DirB\DirC
```

while the corrected pathname being generated looks like this:

```
\\.\C:\DirA\DirB\DirC
```

Reading MSDN's article on [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file), I am a bit confused about what appears to be a number of different ways that a valid pathname can be constructed. It appears that different Windows filesystems (FAT16, FAT32, NTFS, etc.) have different naming conventions.

What is the pathname format I should use so that my application will be able to create and open files in a specific directory on a local drive `C:` with multiple different versions of Windows? I am specifically interested in Windows 7, POSReady 7, Windows 10, and Windows 10 IoT Enterprise (which is not the same as Windows 10 IoT).

I am using the Win32 API `CreateFile()` function to create/open the files.

Comment: *It appears that different Windows filesystems (FAT16, FAT32, NTFS, etc.) have different naming conventions* - no this is wrong. filesystem here at all not related. win32 sunsystem convert your paths native format before pass to filesystem. [The Definitive Guide on Win32 to NT Path Conversion](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html)

Comment: @RbMm thank you for the link to the guide document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the pathname format I should use so that my application will be able to create and open files in a specific directory on a local drive `C:` with multiple different versions of Windows?

You should be using:

```
C:\DirA\DirB\DirC
```

Or, if you need to [access a pathname longer than `MAX_PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation), and don't/can't opt in to the new `longPathAware` feature introduced in Windows 10 version 1607:

```
\\?\C:\DirA\DirB\DirC
```

DO NOT use `\C:\DirA\DirB\DirC`, this is not correctly formatted.

You should not need to use `\\.\C:\DirA\DirB\DirC`, though it *will* work.  Just [be aware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-device-namespaces) that:

> The `"\\.\"` prefix will access the Win32 device namespace instead of the Win32 file namespace.

*Typically*, you would use `\\.\` only when accessing local devices, like physical volumes, serial/parallel ports, named pipes, mailslots, etc.  Not when accessing entries on the file system.

Comment: Network shares are accessed using UNC paths instead, ie: `\\server\share` or `\\?\UNC\server\share`

Comment: but why not `\\.\C:\DirA\DirB\DirC` - this is formal correct form

Comment: yes, however i,if say true, not understand what is mean *will access the Win32 device namespace instead of the Win32 file namespace* the file is always open on device. filesystem file too. so unclear for me

Comment: of course say shell api not convert paths with \\.\ or \\?\ prefix, but for `CreateFile` the filesystem device - this is also device. `\\.\PhysicalDiskX` or `\\.\c:` both is symbolic links to  some device - by fact no any different here, because this i not undertand msdn article

Comment: i be say that \\.\ give the most power. in case `\\.\X:*` it have the same effect as `X:*` but also let access any name inside \??\ sunbolder like \\.\PhysicalDiskX and if use `\\.\global\globalroot\*` this let us to jump root of namespace. different with \\?\ wich do almost the same - but \\?\ was simply replaced \??\ and next path not parsed, while in \\.\ the say / replaced to \ parsed .. and . and so on

Comment: I am changing to your suggested approach and it works fine with Windows 10 and fixes my problem. Using the `\\.\C:\DirA\DirB` approach also worked with Windows 10 however I'm not married to the idea of doing it that way. I think the `\C:\DirA` was due to a defect in trying to move to a standard approach with devices since this application does use devices such as the serial port especially with serial ports higher than `COM9` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/115831/howto-specify-serial-ports-larger-than-com9

Comment: @RbMm you are obviously a low level guts kind of person, you always post comments/answers digging into API internals and such. So maybe you like having more power in your API calls. The typical user does not. Using `\\.\ ` is overkill when accessing the filesystem for simple tasks (creating/reading/writing files, etc), but it obviously does have its uses in more advanced scenarios. This is not one of them.